# How do I get the ip of a running instance using hooks?

Tags: juju

I was wondering how do i get the ip of a running instance of a charm 
using hooks. I need the IP to bind the services of the charm against 
this IP.

So when I deploy my charm I would like to get the IP of the instance and 
then change the configuration of the charm to use this IP to bind 
services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you are looking for are `unit-get private-address` for the
private IP address, and `unit-get public-address` for the public IP
address.

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2014-October/004367.html
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/reference-hook-tools#unit-get